# array based query php

Tags: php, mysql

instead of searching a mysql DB for one variable at a time, i want to search for a number of variables, and fit it into the initial query string

so instead of

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'CA' OR state = 'CO' OR state = 'TX'";
```

i want

```
$states = ("CA,CO,TX");
$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = $states";
```

I have tried

```
<?
include("connect.php"); // file to connect to db
$states = array(CA,TX);
$states_str = implode(",", $states);


$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ($states_str)";

$result=mysql_query ($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['state'];
}

?>
```

but i get this error message

```
 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in  ... on line 11
```

this is line 11

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

however, if i use this code, i get a result, only to show that when i switch back to the old conventional query it works

```
<?
include("connect.php"); // file to connect to db
$states = array(CA,TX);
$states_str = implode(",", $states);


$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'CA'";

$result=mysql_query ($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['state'];
}

?>
```

but then i am bypassing the implode() thing, which i found somewhere else but it is not working for me

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: hmmph ... imagine the work involved when 'somebody' decides they dont like the syntax ... to dive into a zillion lines of code and re-write everything when it is all working fine in the first place is one of the big negatives for me in re PHP. what works one day is gone the next, you have no idea why, and then when u find out u gotta rewrite a lotta code. truly annoying.

Comment: `mysql_query` has been deprecated for a while now, and widely regarded as obsolete for at least five years. Remember "working fine" is a subjective thing. If your code is riddled with SQL injection bugs, it is really **not** fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the query fails because the string values are not quoted.

Try:

```
$states = array('CA','TX');
$states_str = implode("','", $states);
$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
include("connect.php"); // file to connect to db
$states = array('CA','TX');
$states_str = implode("','", $states);
$states_str = rtrim($states_str,",'");


$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";

$result=mysql_query ($query);
if($result){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['state'];
}
}
?>
```

**Thats because your query is failing so first check  for it**

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 include('../testi.inc');

 $states = array('CA','TX');
 $states_str = implode("','", $states);

 $query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE state IN ('$states_str')";

 $result=mysqli_query ($db,$query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo $row['state'];
 }

 ?>
```

or something like that